# Error on retrieving RSS Feed (vb.net project)

Tags: vb.net, rss, feed

So, i'm developing a project on vb.net to manage rss feeds and if they have a file attached it downloads automatically the files to a folder. I know something about vb.net but in Xml i'm having my first steps.

I already managed to properly download content from links with this code i found online:

```
Dim webReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(tsCboFeeds.Text), HttpWebRequest)

webReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip

Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(webReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim xml As String
Using sr As New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
   xml = sr.ReadToEnd()
End Using

doc.LoadXml(xml)
```

It works great for 99% of the feeds i found, the only problem are the ones that have the download url in an enclosure tag, like this example (the link is the url of the post, not the to the file):

```
<channel>
<title>...</title>
<link>...</link>
<description>...</description>

<item>
    <title>...</title>
    <description>...</description>
    <category>...</category>
    <author>...</author> 
    <link...</link>
    <pubDate>...</pubDate>
    <enclosure url="http:..." />
</item>
```

When i try to use

```
Dim nodesLink As XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select("/rss/channel/item/enclosure_url")
```

i dont get the information inside the tag, it gives me back the whole xml doc.

As i mentioned i dont understand that much of Xml, but by now i tried a number of solutions i found online, even changing the method of getting the file, but mainly because of enconding problems this method has been the best for my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your xpath expression is wrong. In the Xml i see an element called  and not an element called .

You could try this:

```
Dim nodesLink As XPathNodeIterator = navigator.Select("/rss/channel/item/enclosure")
nodesLink.Attributes("url")
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your response
I tried writing the nodesLink.attributes, but my project doesn't recognize that property. I already have a bucnh of imports but maybe i'm missing one. the ones i have already import are: 


Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Xml
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Comment: I confused XPathNodeIterator en XmlDocument, sorry for that. I think you should use this code (didn't test it):
`Dim xp As XPathNavigator = nodesLink.Current`
`xp.GetAttribute("url",Nothing)`

Comment: Thanks again for the help. didn't help though :/

I guess the rss is too broken to be read. thanks anyways